# Laravel Query Builder When / If

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to filter out some specific records from a table based on user filter but running into issue on how to properly format it. I have `sales_channel` and `total` columns from `Orders` table.

If `sales_channel == Non-Amazon` then I need to grab all of those records regardless of `total`. Alternatively, if `sales_channel !== Non-Amazon` then I only want to grab records that have a `total > 0`

For my initial query I have the following which works as expected:

```
$orders = Orders::where('sales_channel', '=', 'Non-Amazon')->orWhere(function ($query) {
    $query->where('total', '>', 0);
})->get();
```

However, when a user sends a request to filter data, I'm not sure how to properly filter the request. This is what I currently have where `$request['sales_channel']` is an array of sales channels that they want to return:

```
$request = $request->data;
$orders = Orders::query();

if ($request['sales_channel']) {
    $orders->whereIn('sales_channel', $request['sales_channel']);
}
```

How would I make it so if `$request['sales_channel']` contains `Non-Amazon`, grab all of the Non-Amazon records, but for any other sales channel, `total > 0` must be true.

---

Example:

```
sales_channel | total
--------------+----------------
Non-Amazon    | 19.99
Non-Amazon    | 0.00
Amazon.com    | 11.00
Amazon.com    | 0.00
Amazon.ca     | 22.00
Amazon.com.mx | 19.99
```

User wants to filter by Non-Amazon and Amazon.com results:

`$request['sales_channel'] = ['Non-Amazon', 'Amazon.com'];`

Results would return:

```
sales_channel | total
--------------+----------------
Non-Amazon    | 19.99
Non-Amazon    | 0.00
Amazon.com    | 11.00
```

Comment: can you make example data end expected data for result

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov updated the question w/ an example

Answer (score 1):

use when

```
$orders = Orders::when(($request->sales_channel=="Non-Amazon"),function ($query)use($request){
                 $query->where('sales_channel', $request->sales_channel);
                 })->when(($request->sales_channel!="Non-Amazon"),function ($query)use($request){
                 $query->where('total', '>', 0);
                })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$request = $request->data;
$orders = Orders::query();

if ($request['sales_channel']) {
    $orders = $orders->whereIn('sales_channel', $request['sales_channel']);
}else{ 
    //the initial query
    $orders = $orders->where('sales_channel', '=', 'Non-Amazon')->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->where('total', '>', 0);
    });
}

//check if the orders are filtered correctly
var_dump($orders->get());
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrej, I thought this would work but `$orders` still returns `Non-Amazon` orders even when the request does not contain those.

Comment: I see, I edited the answer, can you check if this works?

Comment: You may need one more condition inside the if($request['sales, to check if !=='Non-Amazon' and add the total query too.